# Printing pages with page number

Tags: c++, winapi, printing

I am making a program on Winapi c++ and I need to print some documents that are generated from my program, but I want to add on the corner of each page a page number, such as "Page 1 of X." I am stuck and don't know how to do this.

To separate pages I'm using the "StartPage-EndPage" method and call them every time when the actual content is bigger than page size, and this all works fine. But the problem is every time I call the EndPage method then HDC becomes empty.

Is there any way I can change the HDC of the page after I called the EndPage method to include a page number? Or maybe I need to do something else. I am new in Winapi so I am not sure how to work with the printer correctly. Maybe there is different way to separate pages instead of "StartPage - EndPage"?

Comment: Why can't you just print the page number to the bottom corner of the HDC before calling EndPage?

Comment: Can you print the page information after the StartPage message?  What happens then?  You may want to use a Printer Device Control object rather than something as generic as HDC.

Comment: In order to print *Page 1 of X*, you have to know before you start printing the report how many pages it will be. You can't go back and print on a page that has already printed.